# What this query doing?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT SalesOrderID
     , SUM(UnitPrice) AS SumOfPrice
     , ProductID
  FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
 WHERE SalesOrderID BETWEEN 44175 AND 44180
 GROUP 
    BY GROUPING SETS(SalesOrderID,ProductID);
```

Can anybody help me in understanding what this query is doing? I am little confused about how `grouping sets` works.

Comment: documentation is a good place to start.

Comment: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=664143&seqNum=10

Comment: Nope. As far MySQL is concerned GROUPING SETS is a new one on me. Perhaps you're using M$SQL?

Comment: nothing on Google when you search for Grouping Sets?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using `MySQL` as opposed to `SQL-Server`, `Access-SQL`, etc.?

Comment: Looks like sqlserver adventureworks database.You might want to change tags to get the attention of the sqlserver community.

Answer (score 0):

A GROUP BY clause that uses GROUPING SETS can generate a result set equivalent to that generated by a UNION ALL of multiple simple GROUP BY clauses.